# Regex to match word in the middle

Tags: python, regex

My current regex

```
^Service\.LT\.fix\.log$
```

matches the below string

```
Service.LT.fix.log
```

How would I change regex so any word before and after LT should pass.

The regex should pass all the below cases:

```
Service.LT.fix.log
Service.BeforeLT.fix.log
Service.LTAfter.fix.log
```

I tried

```
^Service\..+?LT.+?\.fix\.log$
```

but that did not work.

Comment: Use `.*?` instead of `.+?`, that will allow the matching of *nothing*

Comment: that works, but i am not sure why using + didnt

Comment: The `+` quantifier means 1 or more, whereas `*` means 0 or more. Using `.+?` in your regex is like saying there must be at least *something* before `LT`, but this *something* cannot be *nothing*, it needs to be at least of length 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`^Service\.\w*LT\w*\.fix\.log$`